# There is any way to change the 'envFile' variable path in cypress?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress, end-to-end

I have been looking for a way to change the default path of `envFile` of the cypress configuration so I can have my env variables set in a file in other directory,
I just want to move the `cypress.env.json` to other directory. I just dont want to put it in the root directory of the project.

Comment: You could put them in the cypress.json file in a section `env` More details here https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Setting. It is unlikely that you can change the location of the file. It is a convention that these settings file live in the root of the project

Comment: From a quick scan of the [source](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/00a7e69ed267196c778bc3b22f6f8f0e28c30266/packages/server/lib/util/settings.js#L205), it doesn't look possible. You can copy the external file with a package.json script starting with `pre...`, e.g `pretest` if you run tests with the `test` script. npm will always run `pretest` first when you call `test`.

Comment: Thanks @Mikkel, the thing is that I dont want to commit env variables in the repo, because I'm storing passwords there.

Comment: Actually you can use a symlink to a file in a different directory, and then commit the symlink. I use this myself on a few projects already